# How to refer to random numbers in batch files (%random%)

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have come across a rather odd situation.

I have generated a a random number in a batch file, which basically creates a file

e.g. > %random%%random%.txt

Although, if I was to refer to this randomly generated file at a later stage in the script how would I accomplish this? (Baring in mind doing something like *.txt would not work, as there are hundreds of text files).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply save the generated value in a variable.

```
set x=%random%%random%
echo %x%
set filename=file%x%.txt
echo %x%
echo %filename%
find /n /v "" < %filename%
echo %x%
echo %filename%
```

Once they have been assigned using `set`, `%x%` and `%filename%` will not change again.

Comment: @Heath Hunnicutt. Hi this does not seem to work in my script:

Comment: set x=sec_alert%random%%random%%random%.lst

Comment: It generates a different number when using it with the find command

Comment: I just got the following to work.  Are you using a .bat extension or .cmd?  set x=%random%
set filename=file%x%%x%.txt
find /n /v "" < %filename%

Comment: I am using a cmd file, but just tried renaming to bad and the same occurs

Comment: File not found.., as it looks like when executing the find statement, it calls the %x%, but generates the number again!

Comment: @Heath Hunnicutt Can you provide a snippet if yours is working please?

Comment: sorry didnt see above, checking now trhanks

Comment: Output of ver command on my test system: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]

Comment: @Heath Hunnicutt Thanks, as my full script was a little more complicated, I weeded out the problem, the copy command was not set to %filename% as well! Thanks for your help, I appreciate it :)

Comment: @Heath: As a matter of fact, your script does generate the `File not found` error. And that's no wonder, as it doesn't create the file by that name. Other than that, I can't see any abnormal behaviour, and the `%x%` output never changes, once set.

Comment: @Andriy M -- Thanks.  I was aware of that, actually.  I figured OP would be able to work through the example although it was not complete.